# Bridge design pattern with inheritance where abstract base class has member data

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

I use bridge design pattern regularly. But I am confused as to how to use it effectively in an inherited object. Using struct apple::impl :public fruit results in double object fruits. I want to use the abstract base class data member in the implementation

```
class fruit
{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
private:
    int count_;
};

class apple: public fruit
{
public:
    virtual void print();
private:
    int apple_count_;
    struct impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> impl_;
};

struct apple::impl
{
    virtual void print() { cout << "apple"; }
};

void apple::print(){ impl_->print(); }
```

Comment: there are three access modifiers: `public`, `private`, and `protected`. Perhaps take a look at the third.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the Bridge pattern is to separate interface from implementation.  Data members are part of the implementation, so they do not belong on an interface class *or on any of its superclasses*.

If you want inheritable implementation components, such as your data member, then perform the interface / implementation split at a higher level -- e.g. create a `fruit::impl` to hold the member, and have `apple::impl` inherit from that.  Note, too, that the classes on the implementation side do not need to inherit from any of the classes on the interface side, and it would be a clearer and cleaner design for them not to do.

Comment: Agreed. But as a special case I want some member data in the abstract base class which itself can be designed with bridge pattern

Comment: @ark1974, I'm not seeing how that's a special case.  I suppose you must attribute more significance to being "designed with [the] bridge pattern" than just the type of the member, but I'm afraid my crystal ball is a bit cloudy today.